# CPU Usage at 100% with "Hardware Interrupts"

Tags: drivers, bios, hardware-failure, cpu-usage

After turning on my desktop one day, I found that my CPU usage was maxed out at 100%, with most of that going to hardware "Interrupts":

I tried to enable/disable all my devices one by one through the device manager, and found that I could get the CPU usage used by the Interrupts down to 50% by disabling all devices labelled "USB Host Controller" (except the ones for the mouse/keyboard).  I found that I also got 10-20% more from disabling "High Definition Audio Controller".

[image]

Following the tutorial at:
http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/

Led me to similar conclusions (that is, that the culprit is mostly "USB Host Controller"):

[image]

I've tried updating my asus motherboard driver and my video card driver.  This is on Windows 7 64 bit.

I've spent hours trying to figure this out and I'm running out of ideas short of formatting (which might still not fix it!).

Comment: Can you post screen scap of your Task manager ,showing process running tab ?

Comment: Ok, I've added screen shot of task manager

Comment: I had this exact issue (usbport.sys HDAudBus.sys interupts) on a PC, never did figure it out. Assumed it was a driver conflict that could not be sorted out, tried everything, XP had no issues on my hardware, only W7....http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/page__view__findpost__p__920682

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### SOLVED!

All I had to do was update BIOS.  I was previously still using the initial version that came with my motherboard.  In my case I just had to go to the Asus support site, download the latest BIOS, and then follow instructions that I found [here](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20070215223109668&board_id=1) to update it from a USB stick.